# How to get id of clicked item Django

Tags: python, django

Hello i have a list of items in the cart but i would like to decrease, increase and delete items from the cart but I have no idea how to get "pk" of these items. Should i use update view if I do not want to use JS?

views.py

```
class CartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "shop/cart.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.annotate(
        price=Sum(F('orderitem__item__price') * F('orderitem__quantity'))
        ).get(order_user= self.request.user)
        cart = context['cart']
        cart.total = cart.price
        cart.save()
        context['order_items'] = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        return context
    def post(self, request, pk):
        if 'minus' in request.POST:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(order_user=self.request.user)
            OrderItem.objects.filter(id=pk, cart=cart).update(
            quantity=F('quantity')-1)
            return HttpResponse("cart uptaded")
```

Comment: Using JS you can use `localStorage` to temporarily manage the Cart items before going to order confirmation. Usually, this feature don't need backend involvement unless you make a post request to send the objects from `localStorage` to the db

Answer (score 1):

pk is the same as id

in your urls.py:

```
path("yourpath/<int:id>/", view, name='viewname')
```

and in your template:

```
href="{% url 'appname:viewname' object.id %}"
```